# Is this question correctly worded?

Tags: questions

I'm taking some online quizzes in a specific subject and I've faced the following question

Which statement is false?

1- XXX.

2- XXX.

3- XXX

4- No statement is false.

5- All statements are false.

The sentences 1,2, and 3 are true. I've chosen 5 and I got incorrect answer and the teacher said the correct answer is 4. It seems to me the way the question is formulated doesn't test my knowledge in the subject which pisses me off. I would like to know if the question from linguistic point of view is correct or valid so that I can file a claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely as a point of logic, options 4 and 5 are contradictory and immediately cancel each other out, so neither can be the answer. For example, choosing *4 - No statement is false* can't be the answer, because *5- All statements are false* is false :)

I can only presume that the question is poorly worded, and should have been presented as

1. XXX
2. YYY
3. ZZZ
4. 1, 2 and 3 are all true.
5. 1, 2 and 3 are all false.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I though but since I have no choice, I've chosen 5. I thought it is silly if they assume 4 or 5 are actually sentences.